# Should I use Boolean(value) or can I compare directly?

Tags: javascript, boolean, conditional-statements

I usally write this kind of conditions:

```
if (title && content){
// code
}
```

But then I see this example:

```
const canSave = Boolean(title) && Boolean(content) && Boolean(userId)
```

And they used `canSave` to pass in to disabled prop in a button.

Is it a best practice to use Boollean instead of just doing the following?

```
const canSave = title && content && userId
```

In what cases should I use Boolean()?

Comment: Your method are works.

Comment: As long as you remember (or when it does not matter) that `1 && "a" === "a"` while `Boolean(1) && Boolean("a") === true` then they work the same (and I personally prefer the short version). Also note that `!!` does exactly the same (according to specs because `!x` invokes `Boolean(x)`) then `!!1 && !!"a" === true`

Answer (score 1):

The main goal of Boolean function is to convert a value to boolean, in your case makes sense to convert to boolean before assign to a variable because if you try to do it that way:

```
const canSave = title && content && userId
```

the variable `canSave` will assign the value of `userId` and will ignore the rest, but if you convert the values to boolean, the variable `canSave` will assign the result of a comparison between these values. Another reason to use the boolean function could be to convert a value before pass it to a function who only accepts boolean as parameters, like so:

```
const foo = (bar) => {
  if(typeof bar !== "boolean") {
    throw new Error("not a boolean")
  }
  // do something else
}

foo(2) // Error
foo(Boolean(2)) // Ok
```

In this case makes sense to convert the value to boolean, maybe another case would be convert the value before saving to a database. As values like positive numbers, strings, arrays and objects are always **true** and zero or negative numbers, empty strings, undefined and null are **false**, there's some cases that doesn't make sense to convert it, like in a conditional statement, like so:

```
if (title && content && userId) {
  // do something
}
```

These variables will be casts to a boolean already, so converting it will just create redundancy in your code.